# PHP example of the Heroku JSON REST API?

Tags: php, json, heroku

I'm trying to get the app process status with the REST API and am having a bit of trouble getting it to return good data

```
    $ch = curl_init( );

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.heroku.com');  // No clue what to put here. 
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, ":yesthisismyrealapikeyanditworks");   // trust me on this line :)
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json', 'Content-Type: application/json')); //total guess
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'https://api.heroku.com/apps/myapp/ps');  // where myapp is actually my app name

    // Getting results
    return  curl_exec($ch);
```

This hasn't returned anything useful. I'm new to JSON and curl, so go easy on me please. Thanks.

Dave

Comment: _"This hasn't returned anything useful."_ - OK.  So what is it returning?

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete question. I was getting a mix of return data, in one case it was actually creating new dynos for me rather than sending me ps status. No useful errors at all, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ch = curl_init( );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.heroku.com/apps/myapp/ps');
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, ":yesthisismyrealapikeyanditworks");
return  curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Yes! This works. I got wadded up around the axle converting a linux style curl command to PHP. I was seeing good results from the command line with 
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -u :myapikey -X GET https://api.heroku.com/apps/myapp/ps
But couldn't figure out how to make the leap into PHP.